# Is it possible to call another function after smarty display() is called?

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

I am trying to make users download a zip file but prior to that, they would have to fill out a form with some required details.

Basically, I am able to do it but the problem is, when the users submit the form, the page remain as is and the file is downloaded.

What I did was, I created a file that contains the form which calls another file/page that serves as the success page and when it goes to the success page, that's the time the file gets downloaded but as mentioned, the page remains the form page an the file is downloaded automatically.

In my code, I call the function that downloads the file first then the function that calls the smarty template that will be displayed is called after.

But the problem is, it seems like the 2nd function is not executed as all. At first I thought it's the header() that stops the code execution next to it but as I have read, the code after the header() function are still executed not unless *exit* is called.

I have also tried to call the function that would render the smarty page then the function to download the file but it doesn't work. It seems like the codes after the **display()** call are not executed at all?

Is there a way for me to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: forms are normally processed in a dialog of 'show form' then loop: check form: if valid do success actions; else show errors; endloop. So, you only show one form. **either** the download form when you have a valid 'details form' **or** the 'details form with errors.

Answer (score 0):

If for any reason you have problem with display function, you should simple use fetch function instead of display. This way you can use generated content and do anything you want

```
   $siteContent = $smarty->fetch('yourtemplate.tpl');
   // do anything you want
   echo $siteContent;
```